# How can I launch a modern game with DOSBox

Tags: starcraft-2, dosbox, msdos

So I want to know if there is a way to launch a modern game or a modern game Setup (my case, StarCraft-ll), with DOSBox.
I mean that if I mount a directory with starcraft-ll setup, can I launch it like an old MS-DOS Game?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're trying to accomplish but I highly doubt non-DOS games will run with DOSBox. Why do you want to launch SC2 with DOSBox?

Comment: Dosbox is specifically meant for an obsolete operating system. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What's preventing you from trying?

Comment: I've already tried, but I think I'm not doing it right, because I can't run it. I wanted to know how to do it exactly.

Comment: So, again, what are you trying to do? Why are you trying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You (probably) cannot.

DOSBox is for an era of games that are around Windows 98 or earlier.  Basically games that do not use any of the OS layer of modern operating system (we're talking about everything from mouse to sound to graphics).

For your specific question, since Starcraft 2 requires at least Windows XP, it definitely won't work with plain DOSBox.  I guess, in theory, you can get DOSBox to run Windows XP, but it'll be the dumbest setup I've ever seen...

Comment: Agreed. It is pointless to go through all that trouble to run a program through DOSBox that probably works with the current version of Windows.

Comment: This question is like asking how to run Uncharted 3 off of a floppy disk drive. It might *technically* be possible, but it’s clearly not what it’s designed for.

Comment: *Windows 95 or earlier :P